# Using thoughtbot/high_voltage to serve static content

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does the high-voltage rails engine help to serve static content, which can be served from nginx rather than rails app server.

How do i configure that?

Answer (score 2):

High Voltage provides a way to organize and serve static pages while providing a Rails-like interface to those pages via routes and controller actions. High Voltage also allows you to protect those pages behind your Rails authentication code and yields the pages into the layout so you don't have to duplicate headers and footers.

That said, High Voltage is very closely tied into the Rails call stack and it is not possible to configure this to work without Rails.

If your goal is to serve static pages through nginx/Apache without going through the Rails framework, you would be better off placing them in the public folder e.g. `public/static_page.html` and linking to that directly, e.g. `yourdomain.com/static_page.html`. One downside to this is you would have to duplicate the headers and footers of the site. You will need to make sure Rails is not [serving static assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#rails-general-configuration), but that is normally not an issue, as production configures that by default.